# How to include bootstrap font-folder in grunt build process?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I am using [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp), and want to use Bootstraps glyphicons now.

There are not showing and I get this error via Dev Console:
[image]

Bootstrap is including its fonts via those lines:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

The fonts folder is inside the 'src' folder:

[image]

but not inside the 'build folder':
[image]

> So how can I tell grunt to copy this folder during the build process?

Comment: Use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy?

Comment: yesss.... thanks. I am very new to config grunt files, so thanks for the little heads up.